# Нумерация таблицы с N ого числа

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

приветствую)) помогите пронумировать таблицу. Обнулить индексы могу от нулевого, но еще колонка Id должна нумеровать строки с 1461 го номера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не приводите данные картинкой вместо текста. Так их нельзя скопировать, чтобы использовать в качестве тестовых данных для ответа. Только из-за этого я воздержался проголосовать за ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame({"SalePrice": np.random.rand(5) * 10**5})

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
      SalePrice
0  80366.837425
1  26298.060847
2  72747.747090
3  59637.191616
4  86255.679832

In [19]: df["Id"] = np.arange(1461, 1461 + len(df))

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
      SalePrice    Id
0  80366.837425  1461
1  26298.060847  1462
2  72747.747090  1463
3  59637.191616  1464
4  86255.679832  1465
```